# Convert .js.erb to js.haml

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have an ajax code that removes posts from the page:

```
$("#post_delete").on("ajax:success", function(data){
  $("#<%= j @post.id.to_s %>").fadeOut();
});
```

It works only in the erb format, but when I try to use the haml I recieve an error - "Illegal nesting"

```
$("#post_delete").on("ajax:success", function(data){
  $("#" + "#{j @post.id.to_s}").fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In haml you'd have to write your js code like this :

```
:javascript
  $("#post_delete").on("ajax:success", function(data){
    $("#" + "#{j @post.id.to_s}").fadeOut();
  });
```

Comment: I tried this method, but it didn't work. (There was no error, but the post isn't deleted, also I checked `console.log('is it work?')` but it doesn't output nothing).

But using `:plain` problem solved

Comment: using `:plain` where? and its working as expected? or without any error?

Comment: I using `:plain` instead `:javascript` and this working as expected

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#post_delete").on("ajax:success", function(data){
$("##{j @post.id.to_s}").fadeOut();
});
```